# python selenium find_element_by_name

Tags: python, selenium

what is the right code to find the email input for `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?`

the html is `<input id="Email" class="" type="email" spellcheck="false" value="" placeholder="Email" name="Email"></input>`

I'm referencing https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?')
```

for `elem = browser.find_element_by_name()` i've tried:

```
elem=browser.find_element_by_name('input id="Email"')
elem=browser.find_element_by_name('input id="Email" class="" type="email" spellcheck="false" value="" placeholder="Email" name="Email"')
elem=browser.find_element_by_name('input id="Email" class=""')
elem=browser.find_element_by_name('id="Email" class="" type="email" spellcheck="false" value="" placeholder="Email" name="Email"')
elem=browser.find_element_by_name('id="Email" class=""')
```

none of these work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
elem=browser.find_element_by_name("Email")
```

`find_element_by_name` expects the value of the `name` in the line of HTML.  So in the case of `name="Email"`, you would give `find_element_by_name("Email")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the id of the tag

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_id("Email")
```