# Missing 1 required positional argument ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

ERROR:

```
    username_box = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
TypeError: find_element_by_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser

usr = "example1"
pss = "example2"

webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://uonet.uni.opole.pl/login")

driver = webdriver.Chrome
username_box = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username_box.send_keys(usr)
password_box = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password_box.send_keys(pss)

accept_button = driver.find_element_by_id('main')

login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('sub1')
login_button.submit()
```

Is there any solutions or can I write auto login code without selenium?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python selenium find\_element\_by\_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581253/python-selenium-find-element-by-name)

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde This is not a duplicate... see the error: `TypeError: find_element_by_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate the instance of `Chrome` with the path to chromedriver and use the `get(url)` webdriver method

Something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser

usr = "example1"
pss = "example2"

# webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://uonet.uni.opole.pl/login")

# you can spesify in the initiation of Chrome the path to a spcific chromedriver
# like this: driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://uonet.uni.opole.pl/login")
username_box = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username_box.send_keys(usr)
password_box = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password_box.send_keys(pss)

accept_button = driver.find_element_by_id('main')

login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('sub1')
login_button.submit()
```

hope this helps you!

Comment: you don't need to pass the path to initialize it, OP just didn't add parens

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg correct! I just added in case OP did not save chromedriver in default folder... I'll edit... Thanks for your time!