# How to fix NoSuchElementException on webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have tried to log in a portal of Wifi automatically using python. However, `find_element_by_X` gives errors.

I am using Chrome as a browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()



driver.get('https://hinet.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/loginweb.html')
time.sleep(2)
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.button').click()

username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input")
username.clear
#Enter HiroshimaU ID
username.send_keys('input_username')

password = driver.find_element_by_name('pwd')
password.clear
password.send_keys('input_userpassword')
```

This code should work, but it just gives me errors:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input"}

I have tried other methods, such as `by_name` or `by_id`. But none of them is working.

I am a very beginner so my question might not be clear, but I appreciate your help.

Edit(Oct 23, 2019):
I am sorry you cannot access the portal site.
I hope this screenshot may help.
[Portal site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMqaS.png)

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

`Input` is not a valid cssSeletor.

You need top do something like below:

Example:

for https://www.google.com/ website,

cssSeletor of textFiled would be

```
input[name='q']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How should I type `input[name='q']` in the code? `username = driver.find_element_by_name(input[name="uid"])` does not seem to be working.

Comment: Its cssSeelctor so use driver......by_cssSelector , another its an string

Comment: Annother thing wait for long time seems your page not ready just in 2 sec

Comment: Thank you Shubham, I tried to fix to `time.sleep(5)`. So, as for the find_element problem, I tried in fail again ... `username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(input[name="uid"])` gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` And `username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="uid"]')` gives 
 me`Selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name="uid"]"}` .

Comment: I am not able access your website, so check if there is any frame present as parent of this name=uid

Comment: So this is what I want to find :`<input type="text" name="uid" size="14" maxlength="32" autocomplete="off">`. I have added the screenshot of the portal page in my question, so please kindly check it out.

Comment: is there any other element present on DOM with name='uid', see either your page not loaded, or element not loaded in 5 sec OR your element inside an frame OR there is other element present with same name as uid

Comment: I searched DOM for any element with name ='uid', and it was the only one. Also, I changed to `time.sleep(15)`, but I got the same error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, I couldn't get access to the site you mentioned, as it helps to see how the html formed.

Second based on that, I ask you to have a look at [python selenium find_element_by_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581253/python-selenium-find-element-by-name)
It shows how to access element by name as:

```
elem=browser.find_element_by_name("Email")
```

where you can see in the html the name tag of "Email"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I tried `username = driver.find_element_by_name(name="uid")` , but it gives me the similar error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="uid"]"}`. I appreciate your help.